# How to get an easier form of this convolution?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

What would be right approach to evaluate the convolution (integral):

$\int f(\tau')\delta(a\tau + b\tau') d\tau'$

I am not sure if I can rearrange something in this convolution to get an easier representation.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is
$$
   \int f(\tau')\delta(a\tau+b\tau')d\tau'=
\frac{1}{b}\int f(\tau')\delta\left(\tau'+\frac{a}{b}\tau\right)d\tau'=\frac{1}{b}f\left(-\frac{a}{b}\tau\right).
$$

Comment: Firstfully thanks for the answer. Shouldn't it be $b$ instead of $1/b$? Or why is $\delta(a\tau) = \frac{\delta(\tau)}{a}$?

Comment: You are welcome. It is a property of the Dirac distribution. Indeed, $\int f(x)\delta(ax)dx$ then change variable to $y=ax$ and get $(1/a)\int f(y/a)\delta(y)dy=(1/a)f(0)$. So, the property follows.

Comment: Ok makes sense now. Thanks! :)